# Knockout - get dependencys from binding Context of Element

Tags: knockout.js

I have an domElement `<div data-bind:visible: open()>` that I get the context from:
`var context = ko.contextFor(domElement);`

How do I get the value of the `visible`-binding (without having to parse the full `div`-String) from the `context`;

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I can't really think of a situation in which you would actually **need** to do this, I'm only showing it's possible.*

Knockout [exposes its `bindingProvider` instance](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingProvider.js#L73). This is the piece of code that manages the parsing of the `data-bind` attribute string. You can use its `getBindings` method to retrieve an object like: `{ visible: ..., text: ..., etc. }`.

Using this method, you *do* parse the string again, but you'll use the exact same logic knockout already executed earlier upon calling `applyBindings`.

```js
const app = { visible: ko.observable(false) };
ko.applyBindings(app);

const div = document.querySelector("div");

// Collect required knockout info
const divCtx = ko.contextFor(div);
const bp = ko.bindingProvider.instance;

// Get the bindings object
const bindings = bp.getBindings(div, divCtx);

// Get the visible binding's value
const boundToVisible = bindings.visible;

// Use it any way you like
boundToVisible(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="visible: visible">Hello</div>
```